# Is there a way to tell what the download speed is from a site/server

Tags: internet, speed

i'm looking into which ISP i should go with at the place i'm moving into, one ISP which i have been told good things about has data limits (which when breached will drop your speed to dial-up speed) but multiple memberships which, apart from the cheapest membership, have the same data limits (the cheapest has a 10GB data limit)

in their fine print, they say that each different membership has different port speeds, one particular part jumps out at me

> These speeds are the NBN (National Broadband Network) port speed and not the actual Internet data speed which will vary based on numerous factors including destination you are reaching, your network equipment, network congestion etc.

i plan to use the net to download DLC and patch updates for games (particular the insanely large update for the Wii U) and games from Steam (if i find any good one other than this one JRPG) and downloading development resources from free sites like Deposit Files and Mediafire

since one membership with a 1000GB data limit is $145 with the port speed being 12Mbps/1Mbps (cheapest) while another with the same limit is $190 with the port speed of 100Mbps/40Mbps (expensive) i am wondering how i can tell what the speed coming from site is since i don't want to be wasting money on speed that makes no difference (unlike memory which i rather have to spare)

NOTE: the speeds are for a fiber optic network which where my new place is can only connect via fixed wireless which i may not be able to get with this ISP but if i can get this network then good

NOTE 2: most of the resources i get from Deposit Files are always about 200 MB or less, if a resource pack is greater then it's split into multiple archives (like .7z.part) while Mediafire i have to see one bigger than 150MB

NOTE 3: one update patch for a PS3 game is close to 4 GB (Disgaea 4) which i need to get access to the DLC and on the weekend i downloaded 5 GB for the Final Fantasy XIV Open Beta for the PS3 which took almost 5 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer as there are a number of things that can impact the download speeds between yourself and any given site on the internet.

My parents have fixed microwave wireless and it works but can be easily interrupted by weather.  Be aware of that.

The speeds that they mention are the maximum speeds you can get.  Those speeds caps are enforced at the ISP level.  If a server were capable of sending faster, it doesn't matter as your ISP won't let you receive any faster.

All else being equal, the option with the higher speeds will be more likely to allow you download data faster as it won't artificially cap the speeds as soon.  Also, servers like Steam can easily saturate even the fastest connections.

Get the 100mbps connection if you want your 5GB downloads to download quickly.